# Control character handling in cron/mailx

Tags: cron, postfix, mailx

I have a cron job which runs a long script producing lots of output. Some of the output is lines delimited by single carriage returns; when run from the command line, these make the successive lines overwrite each other, providing progress output without overly polluting the backscroll. However, when looking at the output from the cron job, I want to see all these lines without missing any.

Until recently, when I used `mailx` to print the output reports from the cronjob, it would replace the control characters with reverse-video `^M` to highlight them. This was the behavior I wanted, as it left all of the lines visible. Now, however, something unknown has changed (a version upgrade?), and `mailx` prints the control characters as-is, causing them to overwrite each other when mail is printed. How can I reverse this behavior and make `mailx` replace control characters again?

Comment: Is this for the display of mail being read by mailx from a user's mail spool file?

Comment: Yes. The data are raw in the mail spool file; viewing them through `mailx` now prints the control characters directly, rather than escaping/replacing them as I'd prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue lay with `mailx`'s pager setting. It began using `more` for some reason, when previously it had used `less` (which does the escaping). Linking `more` to `less` again restored the old behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output through `tr` before processing it further or sending it.

```
./your-script | tr "\r" "\n" | mail
```

This should replace all carriage return characters with line feeds.

The same would be possible within the crontab:

```
* * * * 2 /path/to/your-script --args | tr "\r" "\n"
```

Comment: I run the script from cron. cron grabs all the stdout entirely on its own and mails it to me. I do not have control over this process. I could change the invocation and rewrite the script, but I did not need to do this a week ago and I don't much want to do it now.

Comment: You could add the `tr` to the respective cronjob: `* * * * * ./your-script --with many params | tr "\r" "\n"`.  Should save you from rewriting the script.